# Laravel 5.1: Enable SQLite foreign key constraints

Tags: php, sqlite, laravel, foreign-keys, laravel-5

In SQLite, foreign key constraints are [disabled by default](http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_enable).

What's the best way to configure Laravel 5.1's SQLite database connection to enable foreign key constraints?  I don't see a way of doing this in
[`['connections']['sqlite']`](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/v5.1.0/config/database.php#L49) in
[`/config/database.php`](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/v5.1.0/config/database.php).

Answer (score 23):

Here's one solution.  In the
[`boot()`](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/v5.1.0/app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php#L14) method of
[`App\Providers\AppServiceProvider`](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/v5.1.0/app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php), add:

```
if (DB::connection() instanceof \Illuminate\Database\SQLiteConnection) {
    DB::statement(DB::raw('PRAGMA foreign_keys=1'));
}
```

Thanks to @RobertTrzebinski for [this blog post](http://trzebinski.info/allow-sqlite-to-use-foreign-keys-in-laravel-4/) regarding Laravel 4.

Comment: Assuming most people are using sqlite for testing, you can actually enable foreign key constraints on a test-by-test basis. Because setting foreign_keys will take effect on statements prepared before the setting was changed, you can simply add this code to a helper method in your TestCase and call it when you need.

Comment: I'm in Laravel 5.5 and with this solution I have a strange behaivor. When I try to ->attach() ONE model to another (many to many relationship): *PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such table: main.cv*... **cvs** is my table and I'm trying **$this->cvs()->attach($cv);** Someone has any similar problem?

Comment: Works for Laravel 5.6

Comment: @bambamboole would you please explain how did you do it? Did you added it to AppServiceProvider or to TestCase? Thanks

Answer (score 6):

For me using a the facade DB within App\Providers\AppServiceProvider in Laravel 5.2 produced error.
Here is my solution:

```
if(config('database.default') == 'sqlite'){
    $db = app()->make('db');
    $db->connection()->getPdo()->exec("pragma foreign_keys=1");
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Since I only want to use this in my tests, but in all tests, I ended up with a simple implementation in the `Tests\TestCase` class like this:

```
 abstract class TestCase extends BaseTestCase
 {
        use CreatesApplication;

        protected function setUp()
        {
            parent::setUp();

            $this->enableForeignKeys();
        }

        /**
         * Enables foreign keys.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function enableForeignKeys()
        {
            $db = app()->make('db');
            $db->getSchemaBuilder()->enableForeignKeyConstraints();
        }
}
```

This works like a charm :-)

Answer (score 3):

You could also activate foreign keys on a per test (file) basis, when the tests actually depend on tables with foreign keys.

Here's a trait: (e.g. `tests/ForeignKeys.php`)

```
<?php

namespace Tests;

trait ForeignKeys
{
    /**
     * Enables foreign keys.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function enableForeignKeys()
    {
        $db = app()->make('db');
        $db->getSchemaBuilder()->enableForeignKeyConstraints();
    }
}
```

don't forget to run the method somewhere in your test set-up chain. I added mine as an override to my TestCase: (`tests/TestCase.php`)

```
<?php

namespace Tests;

/**
 * Class TestCase
 * @package Tests
 * @mixin \PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase
 */
abstract class TestCase extends \Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase
{
    use CreatesApplication;

    ...

    /**
     * Boot the testing helper traits.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function setUpTraits()
    {
        $uses = parent::setUpTraits();

        if (isset($uses[ForeignKeys::class])) {
            /* @var $this TestCase|ForeignKeys */
            $this->enableForeignKeys();
        }
    }

    ...
```

after that you can add it to your tests like so:

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature;

use Tests\ForeignKeys;
use Tests\TestCase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;

class ExampleFeatureTest extends TestCase
{
    use DatabaseMigrations;
    use ForeignKeys;

    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

In newer versions of laravel, specifically 8.x and 9.x, there is a config option to turn on foreign key constraints for SQLite databases.

`config/database.php`

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Str;

return [
    // ...
    'connections' => [
        'testing' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlite',
            'database' => ':memory:',
            // here
            'foreign_key_constraints' => true,
        ],
    ],
    // ...
];
```

In my case I had just not set that option for the testing database.