# Laravel 5.1 - test database with SQLite gives 'no such index' error on migration down()

Tags: php, sqlite, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

The following schema builder code works **perfectly** when running `php artisan migrate` and `php artisan migrate:rollback` on **local** and **staging** (production-like) environment. This will run an `alter table` statement to modify an existing table.

*Note: since rows are empty, there is no need to set `nullable` or `default value` to the `category_id`:*

```
// up
$table->integer('category_id')->unsigned()->index();
$table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onDelete('cascade');

// down
$table->dropForeign('stores_category_id_foreign');
$table->dropColumn('category_id');
```

I'm running my functional tests with **SQLite** using `:memory:` configuration, and I'm getting the following error when the database rolls back (thanks to the `DatabaseMigrations` trait)

```
General error: 1 no such index: stores_category_id_index (SQL: DROP INDEX stores_category_id_index)
```

Why is this happening, is there something I have to configure on SQLite that I don't know of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default SQLite has foreign key support disabled.

You'll need to enabled it manually or use a different DB.

[Laravel 5.1: Enable SQLite foreign key constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31228950/laravel-5-1-enable-sqlite-foreign-key-constraints)

Link above talks about how to do this but essentially you need to find a way to run 'PRAGMA foreign_keys=1' on your functional test environment before tests.

Disclaimer: I've only tried this on Laravel 5