# Laravel 5 testing in memory

Tags: mysql, sqlite, laravel, behat, in-memory-database

I am writing tests via behat for my large Laravel 5 project.

I have a testing copy of my MySQL database in MySQL and a seeder for that database that shares some of the seeders of other environments. All of that works as expected.

However, I tried switching to using a sqlite in-memory database because it would speed up my automated tests dramatically and because I'm running "artsian migrate:refresh ---seeder=TestDatabaseSeeder at the start of every behat scenario.

The problem I'm having is that some of my seed data causes sqlite to throw a very non-descript syntax error but MySQL is completely fine with the seed data.

Ideally, I think, I'd like to have it use MySQL in-memory for performance purposes and to keep the database engine consistent. Is there an easy way with or without Laravel to use MySQL in memory when running tests? A solution that does NOT involve duplicating & editing migration files in a way that makes sqlite happy?

Comment: Well, crystal ball is a myth, so I am afraid you should provide some error messages you facing, related code/schemas etc for us to take a look

Comment: You can try having a look at the [MySQL MEMORY Storage Engine](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/memory-storage-engine.html) which allows in-memory tables. This does however have some drawbacks, such as not having support for foreign keys, which might be a deal breaker in most cases.

Comment: You should edit your question and add this new information. Not everyone reads the comments. Also, if you solved your problem you can add an answer yourself so that future readers also benefit from your experiences. You can even accept your own answer after 48 hours.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It turned out that sqlite didn't like the way ' were being escaped.

"\'" needed to be replaced with "''". And sqlite doesn't support enums so I changed out my migrations and use strings instead of enums.

Comment: this is not the answer of that question -

Answer (score 3):

As of 2019 here is the way to make Laravel PHPunit tests to use the in-memory DB.

#### Setup SQLite In-memory for Laravel / Lumen tests

You have to have the following in place:

1. All database migrations for all the tables and fileds in your DB as you normally do for an actual DB, see [Laravel migrations official docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/migrations).
2. Use the `RefreshDatabase` trait (`DatabaseMigrations` trait for Lumen) in your PHPUnit test class ([official docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/database-testing#resetting-the-database-after-each-test)).
3. Set the following in your `config/database.php` file in `connection` setion:

```
    'testing' => [
        'driver' => 'sqlite',
        'database' => ':memory:',
    ],
```

4. Set the following line in your `phpunit.xml` file in `<php>` section:

```
    <env name="DB_CONNECTION" value="testing"/>
```

Thus as soon as you run your PHPUnit tests, PHPUnit will read `phpunit.xml`, replace the `.env`'s `DB_CONNECTION` variable with `testing`. It will trigger the DB configuration `testing` (which is in-memory sqlite DB) to be used.

The tests with in-memory DB vs disk DB is (according to my experience) ~5-30 times faster. 30 times difference is for small test suite of ~200 CRUD tests all running DB queries on half a dozen tables with some `hasMany` and `belongsToMany` pivot relationships.

#### Refresh Database for Each Test

To run database migrations [to have a clean database before each test](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/database-testing#resetting-the-database-after-each-test) add the following trait the top of your test class (Laravel):

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
// ... then in the class body:
use RefreshDatabase;
```

For Lumen [it should be](https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/6.x/testing#working-with-databases)

```
use Laravel\Lumen\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;
// ...then
use DatabaseMigrations;
```

Do not forget to use [model factories](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/database-testing#writing-factories) to seed the DB with test data if needed.

And yes, the migrations will run before and after each test so your start and finish with clean database after your tests finish (this will have an implications if you seeded the on-disk DB with some data and once in a while switch the tests to run on it instead of running on the in-memory DB).

#### Fix SQLite `Cannot add a NOT NULL column with default value NULL` error

Now you succesfully have set up the in-memory DB testion for your app. As you try to use the foreign keys to cascade changes to some related tables expect the above mentioned error to appear.

If you quickly switch your tests to the on-disk DB (comment out `<env name="DB_CONNECTION" value="testing"/>` in your `phpunit.xml` file) the error disappears. After switch back to in-memory DB check your on-disk DB is not empty. If so run `migrate:refresh` and `db:seed` (here you are assumed to had earlier prepared the DB seeds you need) with `artisan`.

By default SQLite disables the foreign keys. Add the following snippets to your PHPUnit test class to fix this:

```php
// At the file's top to import the DB facade
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;


// In the setUp() method
parent::setUp();
if (DB::connection() instanceof \Illuminate\Database\SQLiteConnection) {
    DB::statement(DB::raw('PRAGMA foreign_keys=on'));
}
```

See [detailed explanations and *more, better, different* solutions here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31228950/laravel-5-1-enable-sqlite-foreign-key-constraints).

Hope this clarifies the subject enough to work seamlessly.